# L2switch in Opendaylight fluorine

Tags: opendaylight

1- Is there any l2-switch app in fluorine?
2- How can I change default table id? Is there any configuration file to change default table id?

Thanks,

Comment: The l2switch project didn't make the Fluorine release distribution - apparently no one's maintaining it anymore upstream. Sorry :)  However you can still download it and build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Comment: The l2switch project is a self-managed project https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/release-process/managed-release.html#self-managed-projects and is not officially included in the release as @TomPantelis mentioned.

Comment: Actually it's not really even self-managed as no one declared it as such, as was done with sxp, tsdr et al. It is not maintained at all by anyone at this point.